# TYPO3 felogin registration via several steps

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18 and basic felogin extension. I need make front end user registration on three steps.

How to do it? Edit felogin extension or extend felogin ? May be exists another way? Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for a registration functionality, not the actual login form to log in existing users.

There are several public extensions within TYPO3 to build that functionality, like:
- sr_feuser_register (https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sr_feuser_register)
- formule (https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/formule)
- sf_register (https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sf_register)
- femanager (https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/femanager)
- datamints_feuser (https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/datamints_feuser)

Since I do not use any of the extensions myself, I do not know which fits your requirements exactly, but all of the above are compatible with your TYPO3 version.